# Disable media queries after the dom is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I've issue with media queries.I want the media queries to not work after the dom is loaded.
I've tried so far this

```
 $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width='+screen.width);
```

from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388967/possible-to-disable-media-queries-or-force-a-resolution-reason-allow-an-iphon)

but still media queries are working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all media queries, use class="mediaSheet" into your media sheets and then:

```
$('.mediaSheet').each(function(){
    $(this)[0].sheet.disabled = true;
});
```

Comment: Where to put the mediaSheet class?

Comment: You can group all you stylesheets containing the @media that you can't to disable and put the class on them. It should look like that: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" class="mediaSheet"/>`

Comment: I can't casue I need that stylesheet but I just want to disable the media queries.

Comment: You put all the media queries on another stylesheet and you're done :)

Comment: that's what I don't need at this stage because stylesheet is created by someone else and I need to make changes within it.

Comment: That's the only way that i know. Why don't you tell this person to make it for you ?