# How to prevent site from being responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have one more problem with my GreaseMonkey based script.

What I want to do is to prevent site from behave as responsive. I mean I want any site to keep its default look while zooming in, I just want scrollbars (both) to appear like on old sites.

I tried putting all site in one div and set its width but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
    var OA_disableResponsive = function(){
      $("body").append('<div id="OA_Container"></div>');
      var winWidth = $(window).width();
      $("#OA_Container").css("position", "absolute").css("width",winWidth);
      var el = $("body").children().not("#OA_Container");
      $("#OA_Container").append(el);
    }
```

It places my container div where I want it to be correctly, but it still doesn't prevent site from changing its look while zooming in.

---[ EDIT ]---

I decided to try something else and it looks like it will work with little help.

```
    var OA_disableResponsive = function(){
      var winWidth = $(window).width();
      var winHeight = $(window).height();
      var docWidth = $(document).width();
      var docHeight = $(document).height();
      var url = $(location).attr("href");

      $("body").append('<div id="OA_Container"><iframe src="'+url+'" id="OA_Iframe"></iframe></div>');
      $("#OA_Container").css("cssText", "  \
        display: block; \
        position: fixed; \
        overflow: scroll; \
        top: 0px; \
        width: "+winWidth+"px; \
        height: "+winHeight+"px; \
        left: 0px; \
        bottom: 0px: \
        right: 0px; \
        z-index: 9999; \
        margin: 0 auto; \
      ");
      $("#OA_Iframe").css("cssText", " \
        position: absolute; \
        width: "+docWidth+"px; \
        height: "+docHeight+"px; \
        top: 0px; \
        left: 0px; \
        bottom: 0px: \
        right: 0px; \
        margin: auto; \
      ");
    }
```

Using this method I have one problem - I can't scroll horizontaly. I'm weak in CSS and I don't know how to make this container div always match window size (isn't that just responsive?) and inside it iframe containing whole page. Also which one should be scrollable? Should I use big iframe and scrollbars that belong to div or rather iframe matching div size with its own scrollbars?

Comment: Please post your html and css here as well.

Comment: Use specific pixels instead of % as margin, padding, width and height for all your page elements to avoid a responsive layout btw

Comment: If I was doing it on my own site I wouldn't even ask, there are tutorials. I have script working on every site I'm visiting and I wanna have that option in it.

Comment: btw "css("position", "absolute").css("width",winWidth);" could be an object ".css({"width":winWidth, "position":"absolute"})" ...

How in the world can we know what site "looks" are changing and how to prevent that from happening without posting the full code&style of your page..

Comment: i just wanna put whole site into one big div which is supposed to cover all the window and not beeing responsive, so as consequence of this whole site won't be responsive. And it must work on any site, doesn't matter how the site looks like.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I changed code so it works better, but still not good. May you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to remove responsiveness from sites is to modify the viewport to stick to a certain width.

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1440');
});
```

> Via-
>   [Possible to disable @media queries or force a resolution? Reason: Allow an iphone to see the desktop site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388967/possible-to-disable-media-queries-or-force-a-resolution-reason-allow-an-iphon)

Comment: Bless your soul. You are a life saver. These 3 lines of code solution helped cut down on many man working hours which could easily have turned to days in the long run. +1 for this elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxL8kqpk/1/)

You may have been missing `display:block`.

It is difficult to tell since you only provided the `Javascript` while also saying the JS is the only part of your program that works.

Note that your implementation does not disable `media` queries so you are not entirely disabling responsiveness with this.

Comment: Tried it, not working. And I can't provide any html/css because it's supposed to work on any site, this is the tricky part. I also have no idea how to eliminate all media queries, this could work.