# Disable all the @media rules altogether

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

Does anyone know is there a way to disable all the @media rules altogether in one shot?  I simply want to stop all the @media rules coming from the external libraries that I’m using in my project that applies responsive css to different media types/devices.

Tried to tweak the viewport meta tag but didn't work as I expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to disable @media queries or force a resolution? Reason: Allow an iphone to see the desktop site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388967/possible-to-disable-media-queries-or-force-a-resolution-reason-allow-an-iphon)

Comment: Check this [Is there any way to disable media queries under certain conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583441/is-there-any-way-to-disable-media-queries-under-certain-conditions)